# PyQGIS: error message "Cannot run algorithm wrong parameters for method" when trying to use GRASS tool

Tags: raster, pyqgis, grass-gis

For my QGIS plugin, I'm trying to use the GRASS Tool r.neighbor. I wrote the following code which should run the tool and return the result as a raster object.

```
    def focalStatistics(self):
    raster = self.merge()
    outDir = os.path.join(QgsProject().instance().homePath(), "Extrapolation.tiff")
    param = {"input": raster,
             "selection": None,
             "output": outDir,
             "method": 'maximum',
             "size": 3,
             "title": 'extrapoliert',
             "weight": None,
             "gauss": None,
             "quantile": None
             }
    focalstat = processing.run('grass7:r.neighbors', param)
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(focalstat['output'])
    QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
    return rlayer
```

The needed parameters I looked up from [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.neighbors.html)

However, I get the following error message:

> Cannot run algorithm wrong parameters for method

I don't see the problem, the parametrs should be correct. Can someone explain the error to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know if it's a typing error, but your indentation is wrong. 
I think your problem comes from the definition of the method.

The following code works, I have:

- removed self everywhere
- indicated the path of my raster directly
- in the parameters I replaced the maximum by the corresponding index
- replaced processing.run by processing.runAndLoadResults: the result is automatically added to the project

```
def focalStatistics():
    raster = "C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/test/grass_raster/MNT_SICOVAL_20m_cc43.tif"
    outDir = "C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/test/grass_raster/MNT_SICOVAL_20m_cc43_test.tif"
    param = {"input": raster,
             "selection": None,
             "output": outDir,
             "method": 4,
             "size": 3,
             "title": 'extrapoliert',
             "weight": None,
             "gauss": None,
             "quantile": None
             }
    focalstat = processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:r.neighbors', param)

focalStatistics()
```

Comment: in the original code of my editor, the indentation was correct. What solved the problem finally was to remove the 'maximum' with the indexnumber, which is weird because according to the documentation "method" expects a string and not integer. But ok it works now. Thank you